# How can I better control which functions are ran under pytest_bdd?

Tags: pytest, pytest-bdd

I have a `pytest_bdd` test suite, where scenarios are defined in `*.feature` files and the associated test steps are defined in a `_test.py` file.  For a given group of tests, I'll have a set of `*.feature` files and a single `_test.py` file in a single folder.

When I want to run my tests against production, I want to filter so that only those scenarios marked as `@production_safe` are ran.  I have built out the `pytest_bdd_before_scenario` hook in my `conftest.py` to skip any scenarios that do not have this marker - and that works great.

My challenge is - if I have a test function in my `_test.py` file that is named something like `test_step_one` then that function is automatically picked up by pytest and executed independently of my scenarios.  Changing the `python_functions` parameter in pytest.ini results in none of my scenarios being picked up (because pytest_bdd under the hood creates a bunch of `test_*` functions).  How can I block these test steps from being unintentionally picked up by pytest?

I have tried working with python_classes, python_files and python_functions in pytest.ini, but anything that blocks these step functions seems to also block picking up the pytest_bdd test functions.

Comment: I think it would be easier to answer your question if you post example code. 

Otherwise, pytest already allows you to specify a set tests to be executed by marks. Maybe it fixes already your problem. In your case to run only the tests with mark  `production_safe` you would run `pytest -m production_safe`. See https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/how-to/usage.html#specifying-which-tests-to-run